# Joomla 3.1 - Login to admin section only from one host possible

Tags: php, joomla

it seems to be a pretty common issue that the login to the admin section is not working properly.

But I haven't found anything for the scenario I am facing.

I have set up a Joomla 3.1 on a host of mine, uploading the files from my local PC to the web server.

I have set up the page and all is working fine.

The problem I have is that I am able to log into the admin section (page.com/administrator) when opening it from my local PC without any issues.

But when I try to open the same page from my tablet, phone, other PC, laptop, I get the message 'Ussername and password dont match'.

I checked my credentials multiple times and they are right.

So, question is: why can I log into the admin section from this one computer, but not from any other one? Is there a setting I missed? I did not fiddle around in any system settings up to now, so feel free for any kind of advice :)

Thanks, Tobias

Comment: Sounds really weird. There is no indication for any IP-based access restriction and the provided error message also suggests otherwise. I would try to create a test user with a simple password and see if that one can log in from the other machines before testing further.

Comment: Are they pointing to the same ip address? Maybe you modified your hosts file on your local PC?

Comment: @MasterAM, I did the test with setting up a new user. That new user was able to access to admin section from every device I used for testing. So I took a look at the database and in the users table, two things were weird: first, the activation column had a 0 in it for the super user account and no params json. The test user had nothing in activation and a json in params. I resaved my super user, now the json is there. I manually set activation to blank. Still this one user only works from one device. To make sure I'm not crazy I created a second test user and this one also works perfectly fine

Comment: Can you step through the authentication process with a debugger and try to figure out what's wrong? I simply cannot reproduce this. Can you try to change the admin's password?